# How to read/get event data from Shift digital chrome extension using C# selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

in My test , I need to use ShiftDigital analytics debugger (chrome extension). my site has many forms and this extension captures the event.

**Test Steps:**

- Fill and submit the form
- Verify a "FormSubmission" event should be recorded in the extension

Manually I can view and verify the same but How to do that using selenium C#? Image attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFNSp.png)

I can get data from console using
`sdDatalayer.<field>` but that doesn't capture the event. Rest of the filed I want is there

**Project setup
**
Selenium 4, Specflow, chrome